# "DataTable" CSS style gone after jquery load

Tags: javascript, css

my php file "zero3data.php"

```
<?php  
        printf('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">');
        printf('<thead>');
        printf('<tr>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">#</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Reference</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Customer</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Unit</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Payment</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Accessories</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Points</th>');
        printf('<th rowspan="2">Log</th>');
        printf('<th colspan="2">Approval</th>');
        printf('</tr>');
        printf('<tr>');
        printf('<th>Group Manager</th>');
        printf('<th>Main Branch</th>');
        printf('</tr>');
        printf('</thead>');
        printf('<tbody>');                                  

            require_once("config/db.php");
            $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            $result = $db_connection->query('SELECT * FROM reservationvw  ORDER by logsubmit DESC');
            for($i=1;$row=$result->fetch_object();$i++) {               
                printf("<tr class='gradeC'>");      
                    printf("<td class='center'>%d</td>", $i);                       
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s</td>", $row->reference);
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s <br/> %s</td>", strtoupper($row->cust_name), $row->cust_addr);                
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s/%s/%s/%s/%s</td>", $row->model, $row->variant, $row->enginefuel, $row->transmission, $row->color);
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s/%s</td>", $row->payment, $row->insurance);                        
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s</td>", $row->accessories);
                    printf("<td class='center'>%3d</td>", $row->points);    
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s</td>", $row->logsubmit);
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s</td>", $row->approved);
                    printf("<td class='center'>%s</td>", $row->main_approved);                      
                printf("</tr>");
            }   
            printf('</tbody>');
            printf('</table>');

        ?>
```

my div tag in zero1.php

```
<body id="dt_example">      
            <div id="container"> 
                <div id="demo"> 
                         <div id="content"></div>
                </div> 
            <div>  
</body>
```

now i have my script that load my php to "content", table structure is rendered fine, however, CSS style was gone, my table is tailored with DataTables plugin can be found here http://datatables.net/usage/ ... anyways, heres my script.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content').load('zero3data.php'); 
});
</script>
```

here's what i tried so far.. table rendering was fine but still no css style

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'zero3data.php',
    success: function(data) {    
    $("#content").html(data).trigger('create');
    }
    });
```

i tried this one too...

```
$('#content').load('zero3data.php',function(){ $('#content').trigger('create'); });
```

i even copied necessary css styles zero1.php to zero3data.php, thinking that styles should be loaded again...

here's my head from zero1.php if it helps..

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico" />

    <title>DataTables example</title>
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "../../media/css/demo_page.css";
        @import "../../media/css/demo_table.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: check the path to your style sheets, it's probably not `../../media/css/` on your installation.

Comment: i did that, i made sure css paths are called correctly, also, console log didn't show any problems regarding css loading...

Comment: and by the way, css is working fine if its done without jquery.load() and that the whole thing is in one file (zero1.php)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `@import` with direct links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/demo_page.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/demo_table.css" />
```

Because CSS silently ignores things it doesn't understand, I'm not sure the console.log would show an error. Using the construction above, you can verify the correct paths, even looking at the style sheet contents directly in web inspector.

Comment: thanks.. but nothing's change, same output... log didn't indicate any path problems